# Window Insulation Kit, how much temperature increase?

Tags: heating, windows, heat

I am looking to buy a window insulation kit. How much temperature increase would it cause? I live in an area where it goes 45 degrees Fahrenheit during the winters.

[https://www.amazon.com/3M-Indoor-Window-Insulator-5-Window/dp/B00002NCJI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002NCJI)

[image]

Comment: You'll probably make your money back on heating costs, but don't expect miracles from a thin sheet of film, especially if the existing windows are not fully draught-proof.

Comment: They are not so much insulation, but sealing kits.  They help by stopping warm/cold air from passing though the window, usually at the sides(wall and window frame) and any gaps if the window opens.  They make the house more comfortable by stopping drafts from windows.

Comment: Does not "cause  a temperature increase." Assuming your heat is controlled by a thermostat, it should reduce the amount of fuel you use for maintaining a particular temperature difference indoors to outdoors. Properly applied, these kits are quite effective, particularly with windows that leak a lot, as the properly applied film does not leak (we'd see it bulge out into the room on the side the wind was blowing from.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the temperature is controlled by the thermostat, this product will not cause any temperature increase at all.

This product is a window insulation kit and, if properly installed, should reduce heat (not temperature) loss through the window.  The net result should be a reduction in energy cost through the window.

The amount of heat loss prevented is quite difficult to determine in advance as it depends on a number of factors.  The best way is to use an infrared heat sensor camera before and after installation and one on of the tools that come with those types of camera to estimate the heat loss reduction.

Comment: Not all temperature is controlled by the thermostat - I have a wood burner that is controlled by how much wood I put on, the amount the vents are open, the thermal combustibility of the wood, etc. Yes, it will be, if it's central heating!

Comment: You implicitly assume the thermostat is in the same room, even in the right part of the same room.  If the thermostat is in another room, the room with the improved windows will get warmer because it will lose less heat